# Admob best practice: how many times do I request, and how long should I show a banner ad?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, admob

In my current app project, I request an admob banner only once when the app first loads, and then show/hide it throughout the entire app.

Is this best practice or should I request a new banner everytime a new level loads? Also, will it make a difference in revenue if I show ads only for a short time in my pause menu and hide them throughout the rest of the game.

Comment: I also noticed that banner ads refresh automatically, so do I need to request them just once?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should set your banner ads up to refresh every 30-60 seconds.
I would recommend that you display them continuously throughout your game, don't show and hide them.

For interstitial ads you should request an ad on start up and them display it at a significant break point in your app, such as before/after a new level. You then need to request another interstitial ad.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the best practice is to show ads at the start of each level rather than showing it in the first level only.

If you do this you might not get that many clicks, and you can be only paid for showing ads for a particular time.

For a good revenue you have to show ads in each level and make sure your users aren't frustrated by ads.

Set a decent #NO of ads in your game, show more ads for more clicks.

Comment: Thanks for answering. On the settings scene of my banner ad in admob it says it refreshes every 30 seconds? Does this mean that it will request an ad automatically without affecting my clicks. Currently, if I request a new banner everytime, sometimes it takes a long time for an ad to show up. Also, just to clarify, does the duration of how long I show an ad make a difference as well?